# Trying to set default param value in stored procedure but errors on CONVERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Wish to set default value in stored procedure but running into error, `CONVERT` doesn't seem to exist. `CONVERT` works in the body but not in the params section of the stored procedure. How do I set param `@StartDate` to a default of 24 months in the past?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProc]
    @Id INT = NULL,
    @startDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, -1 * 24, GETDATE())),   -- last 24 months
    @endDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @startDate;
END
GO
```

Comment: You can only use literal values for parameter defaults. Unfortunately the syntax will pretend to accept expressions, but only because it will interpret them as unquoted strings. And, of course, trying to convert the *string* `'CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())'` to a `DATETIME` will fail. Use `NULL` instead and then set the values with either a test or `ISNULL`.

Comment: That Works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That works!

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[MyStoredProc]
    @Id int = null
    ,@startDate datetime = null
    ,@endDate datetime   = null
as
begin
    SET @startDate = ISNULL(@startDate, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, -1*24, GETDATE())));
    select @startDate;
END
GO
```